# Symbol overprinted on the screen when opening keyboard in Ionic application

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, keyboard, capacitor

I am developing an application with Angular and Ionic. In some android devices,not all, when the keyboard is deployed, a symbol similar to greater than ">" appears overprinted on the screen. It only appears for a few moments and only when the keyboard is displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt8TM.png)

To deploy the keyboard it uses "@capacitor/keyboard":"^4.1.1", I have tried updating it to the latest version but the same thing still happens.
I don't know if anyone else has had something similar happen or how it could be solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: check your code, sounds like you have an extra > character thats not supposed to be there.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I looked in my code and didn't see any loose ">"....  I don't know where to look anymore...

Comment: It's possible that it could be in the CSS, perhaps as the value for a `content` style. Although, given how blurry it is, it could likely be an image. Try inspecting the elements on the page, or slowly commenting out sections of code until you see it disappear to narrow the search

Comment: Solved! The problem came from not adding the mode:'md' attribute in the ion-back-buttons